# Sending a struct with accidental wrong bytes between two computers

Tags: c++, struct

I am sending a struct as a byte stream using TCP socket from one system to another. Both systems are little-endian and the struct does not have any floating number. In summary structs in both systems have the same size (the same padding/alignment is done for them both).

When I receive the byte stream, I store it in `buffer` and then re-construct the struct `waveShortMessage` as following:

```
// Receiving Side
waveShortMessage tmp;
memcpy(&tmp, &buffer, sizeof(tmp));
```

Everything works as expected and I can extract different variables of the struct. The question is, how I can make sure that the byte stream in buffer belongs to a struct. In other words, is there any safety check so that the program notifies the user if the received byte stream does not belong to a waveShortMessage struct. I am particularly interested into a solution that does not involve changing the source code in sender side.

Comment: What do you want to protect against? Accidental wrong bytes in the stream or malicious bytes in the stream? The former is easy, the latter not so much.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Accidental wrong bytes.

Comment: Then you could add a field to the struct that holds some hash of the other fields. If, after receiving, the hashes don't match, something went wrong. (There are probably better solutions, I have no experience with this, but this it what jumps to mind.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen: What if I do not have access to the source code in the sender side? Is there any workarounds?

Comment: @ManiAm Unless there is some class invariant that can be broken (obvious nonsense values), I don't see a way. And even then, the probability of accidentally hitting some "valid values" may be greater than desired.

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols.

Comment: Unless there are some fixed bytes in the structure then there is no way general way to check the structure integrity. If each of the fields in the structure has a domain then each field can be validated separately.  Since  you are using TCP, don't worry about stream integrity as the protocol handles it for you.

Comment: What EJP suggests is probably the better solution I assumed exists above. :)

Comment: A standard way to verify the integrity of a packet of bytes is to tack on a CRC at the end. See Boost. That's how network protocols verify their data packet integrity. Even a small one ( 8 bits) will catch all single bit errors and about 99.6% of all possible bad packets.  It does require changing the source code to add it. Since you are already using TCP you should be quite safe already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing hidden in some arbitrary sequence of bytes that specifies what these bytes "belong" to.

A sequence of bytes is just that: a sequence of bytes. Eight bits in each byte. A given number of bytes, in sequence. Raw data.

If you were to look up the formal specifications of popular Internet protocols like HTTP or SMTP (they're widely available, just a Google search away), you will find that all these high level network protocols consist of fully fleshed-out, structured communication conventions. An email or a web page does not just get blasted across the intertubes as some mysterious, amorphous bag of bytes.

These kinds of communications between two parties, whether it is to send an email, or a web page, follows a well-defined, step by step procedure. A connection is made, and the parties in question exchange various pleasantries over the network connection, before getting down to business, by transferring the data in question.

Then, the data itself also follows a well-defined structure. Web pages are coded in HTML, with some ancillary data like CSS. Email messages have a well-defined structure: a set of header lines, with each header line itself following a well-defined convention, a blank line, then the content of the message. And so on.

So, when an email message, or a web page, is sent between the sender and the receiver, neither one has any doubt, or any reason to be confused about what the heck is this all about.

You are correct in feeling not satisfied with just blasting a binary blob containing your structure across a socket connection, and hoping for the best. Instead, you will need to gather your requirements, sit down, and over the course of a few minutes... or maybe a few hours... or maybe even days, and come up with a protocol for exchanging or transmitting the information that's carried in your binary structure.

And then, all you have to do is implement the whole thing.

Then, your sender and the receiver will have no doubt, or uncertainty, about the information that's being sent or received.

Comment: Good answer. I would add "using a mature protocol library" (I think google protobuf is still a common option) rather than reinventing your own lopsided wheel.